# I'm new to VB and I am stuck on my homework

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have to read in a file of students names and grades, and put each category into a seperate array, such as all the homework1 grades in one array, homework2 grades in another, etc, but I have no idea how to even do this. This is my code so far, and I'm sure most of it is wrong, and I have an error messages.

```
Public Class frmGrades

    Dim FirstName As Array
    Dim LastName As Array
    Dim HW1 As Array
    Dim HW2 As Array
    Dim Project As Array
    Dim Midterm As Array
    Dim Final As Array
    Dim Average As Array
    Dim record, fields(7) As String
    Dim inFile As StreamReader
    Dim outFile As StreamWriter



    Private Sub cmdReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdReport.Click
        MsgBox("Summary report has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Grades")
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmGrades_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        inFile = File.OpenText("Grades.csv")
        outFile = File.CreateText("Report.csv")

        Do While (inFile.Peek <> -1)
            record = inFile.ReadLine
            fields = Split(record, ",")
            FirstName = CInt(fields(0))
            LastName = fields(1)
            HW1 = fields(2)
            HW2 = fields(3)
            Project = fields(4)
            Midterm = fields(5)
            Final = fields(6)
            'Average = (HW1 * 0.0833) + (HW2 * 0.0833) + (Project * 0.1666) + (Midterm * 0.3332) + (Final * 0.3332)
            outFile.Write(FirstName)
            outFile.Write(LastName)
            outFile.Write(HW1)
            outFile.Write(HW2)
            outFile.Write(Project)
            outFile.Write(Midterm)
            outFile.Write(Final)
            outFile.WriteLine(Average)
        Loop

    End Sub


    Private Function Split(ByVal record As String, ByVal p2 As String) As String()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function




End Class
```

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: My error messages are value of type "String" cannot be converted to system.array And it is too late to drop it, I have to take this class to graduate.

Comment: A tip for the future: don't include the word `homework` in your title if you want more views... :)

Comment: @OlleSjögren Already 20+ views in 20 minutes. I'm thinking about putting `Homework` in all my titles!

Comment: @DanVerdolino Hmm, you have a point! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirstName, LastName, etc. are arrays of strings, and I think this was the point on confusion. Be careful just submitting this homework without understanding it and think about making some changes to things you don't understand.

```
Dim FirstName() As String
Dim LastName() As String
Dim HW1() As Single
Dim HW2() As Single
Dim Project() As Single
Dim Midterm() As Single
Dim Final() As Single
Dim Average() As Single

Dim fields() As String
Dim inFile As StreamReader
Dim outFile As StreamWriter

Private Sub frmGrades_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    inFile = File.OpenText("Grades.csv")
    outFile = File.CreateText("Report.csv")
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim seperator As String = ", "
    Do While (inFile.Peek <> -1)
        ' read the fields from the current line in the file
        fields = inFile.ReadLine.Split(",")
        ' redim all the arrays to the appropriate size
        ReDim Preserve FirstName(n)
        ReDim Preserve LastName(n)
        ReDim Preserve HW1(n)
        ReDim Preserve HW2(n)
        ReDim Preserve Project(n)
        ReDim Preserve Midterm(n)
        ReDim Preserve Final(n)
        ReDim Preserve Average(n)
        ' set the values from the fields
        FirstName(n) = fields(0)
        LastName(n) = fields(1)
        HW1(n) = Single.Parse(fields(2))
        HW2(n) = Single.Parse(fields(3))
        Project(n) = Single.Parse(fields(4))
        Midterm(n) = Single.Parse(fields(5))
        Final(n) = Single.Parse(fields(6))
        ' calculate the average
        'Average = (HW1 * 0.0833) + (HW2 * 0.0833) + (Project * 0.1666) + (Midterm * 0.3332) + (Final * 0.3332)
        Average(n) = Single.Parse(
            (HW1(n) * 1 / 12) +
            (HW2(n) * 1 / 12) +
            (Project(n) * 1 / 6) +
            (Midterm(n) * 2 / 6) +
            (Final(n) * 2 / 6))
        ' write a line to the output file
        outFile.WriteLine(FirstName(n) & seperator & LastName(n) & seperator &
                      HW1(n).ToString() & seperator & HW2(n).ToString() & seperator &
                      Project(n).ToString & seperator & Midterm(n).ToString() & seperator &
                      Final(n).ToString() & seperator & Average(n).ToString())
        n += 1
    Loop
    inFile.Close()
    outFile.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! One question, what does the .Parse do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Single.Parse() converts a string to a Single. I see you used CSng(), which should work just fine.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.parse.aspx,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: By the way Allison, welcome to Stack Overflow. Read the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq to get you started. Also, if this or any other answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since an array is one way of collecting multiple values into a single variable, you want to ADD your values to the appropriate arrays.  The code in your while loop is, if anything, replacing each whole array with a value from fields -- this is, in fact, the source of your error message: you're trying to put a string into a variable declared to be an array.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that then. That code was taken from my teachers powerpoints which basically does the same thing my homework is suppost to do, only mine does not work.

Comment: It looks like you might want to change the variables at the top of your class from type `Array` to type `String`. And I'm guessing you might also want to put commas between each field when you're writing to `outFile`, since it's a csv. Something like `outFile.writeLine(FirstName & "," & LastName & "," & ...`

Comment: That's what I had originally with all my variables as type String, and when I emailed my professor, he told me to declare them all as Arrays but maybe he meant to do that in a different spot?

Comment: I don't see any reason for them to be declared as arrays... It looks like all you want to do is get one value for each field from the input file, and write straight to the output file. I would ask the professor for clarification as to why he wants arrays.

Comment: Do you need them all declared separately like you did? Or could you use one single array to hold all the values?

Comment: I need them all separate because I have to print them on the form in separate labels. So on the left I am suppost to have a list of all the students names, and then on the right I have 5 labels that will have each grade in one of them. And then I can click on another students name and it will show that students grades in the labels.

Comment: These are my directions for the homework, Reads each line of data (student first name, student lastname, hw1, hw2, project, midterm, and final grades) ONLY ONE TIME from a file called grades.csv into 7 individual arrays. In addition, you will  rearrange and concatenate the names and place them into an unsorted ListBox as indicated further below.

Comment: It's difficult to answer, because your code serves some purpose, but we don't know exactly what your professor expects. You could have a 2D array that holds all the students' info, which would be relatively simple to manage... if you want to be able to display any student's info at a later time, it makes sense to store it all in memory so you don't need to read the file each time.

Comment: When I emailed my teacher my code, this is what he sent back to me, "FirstName, LastName, Hw1, etc. MUST be declared are arrays, which means any reference to them must be indexed." That is why I changed all my variables to arrays. But I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Understood. So he wants you to have an array of `FirsName`s etc., which holds the first names etc. of all the students. Thinking about this and will post an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your professor might have told you to do like this,

```
 Dim cnt as integer=0

 Do While (inFile.Peek <> -1)

            record = inFile.ReadLine
            fields = Split(record, ",")
            FirstName(cnt) = CInt(fields(0))
            LastName(cnt) = fields(1)
            HW1(cnt) = fields(2)
            HW2(cnt) = fields(3)
            Project(cnt) = fields(4)
            Midterm(cnt) = fields(5)
            Final(cnt) = fields(6)

            cnt += 1
           ..............
           ..............
 Loop
```

Comment: Allison, based on your last comment on Scott's answer, this is what you're looking for.